# Is the polynomial degree (difference) a valuation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-curves, rational-functions, valuation-theory, function-fields

Let $k$ be a field and $K=k(x)=\{f/g\mid f, g\in k[x], g\ne 0\}$ the field of rational functions. Let $\mathcal{O}$ be the ring 
$$\mathcal{O}=\{\frac{f}{g}\in K\mid \deg f\ge\deg g \}\cup\{0\}$$
Then $\mathcal{O}$ is a valuation ring since for any $f/g$ either $\deg f\ge \deg g$ or $\deg g\ge\deg f$. Thus the natural homomorphism $\nu$ defined by
\begin{align*}
&\nu: K^\times \to\mathbb{Z}\cong\frac{K^\times}{\mathcal{O}^\times}\\
&\nu: \frac{f}{g} \mapsto \deg f-\deg g\end{align*}
is a discrete valuation. Let $P=\{a\in\mathcal{O}\mid \nu(a)\gt 0\}$ the non-units of $\mathcal{O}$, I expect this to be the unique maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}$. However since $x, x+1\in P$ this shows that $1\in P$ if it's an ideal, while $\nu(1)=0$ hence $1\notin P$. What was wrong in the above argument?

===================

Update: I understand the problem: $\mathcal{O}$ is even not a ring since it is not closed under addtion:
$$\frac{1-x}{x}+1=\frac{1}{x}\notin \mathcal{O}$$

Comment: it's a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3370152/is-the-polynomial-degree-difference-a-valuation your $P$ is $= \pi O$ with $\pi$ any element of $O$ of minimal non-zero valuation (here of valuation $1$) and $O^\times = \{a \in O,v(a)=0\},O=O^\times\cup \pi O$ shows it is the unique maximal ideal. Be careful that unique maximal ideal (what we obtain after localization of a ring at a maximal ideal) is not sufficient to ensure it is a DVR, we also need that the maximal ideal is principal.

Comment: @reuns: the link you provided points to this self question. could you provide a new one? Thanks

Comment: sorry https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3366490/show-that-f-g-in-kx-mid-degg-geq-degf-is-a-discrete-valuation-rin/3366511#3366511

Comment: That one has a reversed inequality. But I think I understand why my example is not a valuation ring now.